# Question about make several request to a server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How i can make several requests to a server all at the same time, but preventing the mix of the responses?

Comment: sounds like a philosophical statement

Comment: Can you show the code you are using? You can do this without any mix-ups.

Comment: I think he mean order or the responses? We have covered this before.

Comment: Probable Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371277/maintain-order-of-requests-when-making-several-ajax-callbacks

Comment: Surprised at the number of down votes, thought it was quite clear.

Comment: Is not a philosophical question or anything of that i didn't put code because are normal request to the server, but i miss the response from the server.

Comment: You should always post a reduction of the problem, it's very hard to help when you just say "it's not working"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the ajax requests is made separately and you should set them up so that they go to different handlers when the ajax request is finished. The handlers may not be called in the same order since each may take longer than another.

If your code requires that they come back in the same order, you should create a single call that returns all the values you need. Or you need to queue the responses until they have all been processed

Comment: No i don't care about the order of the responses is that one of the responses is missing, and is the first one, the others has no problem.

Comment: I solved the problem was because i was using the same instance to make the request, thanks!

Comment: Did you solve it by trying to create a reduction? That often does it for me.